# Bootstrap offcanvas sidebar toggling for any canvas size

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Could you please explain how offcanvas sidebar toggling works?

I can't make the actual sidebar disappear for sm. I can make the button visible (visible-sm), but toggling doesn't work - the sidebar is always visible.

Toggling works for xs size, that's fine, but I want to make it work for sm the same way, or any other size for that matter.

---

**Partial answer**: Changing `max-width` in offcanvas.css makes toggling work for bigger sizes as well, sm in this case:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  /* 991px instead of 767px makes toggling work for sm as well */

  .row-offcanvas {
    /* ... */
  }

  /* and so on */
}
```

**But** there's still a problem - when canvas width is between 780 and 991px, the sidebar is visible even if it's toggled off. Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: Where is the relevant code...?  what are we supposed to do with the image..? O.o

Comment: Here's the code http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### How does the Bootstrap off canvas example works?

The Bootstrap offcanvas example uses the grid system. For xs screens, the content spans 12 columns (full screen width) and sidebar spans 6 columns (1/2 screen width).

Normally the sidebar would be pushed under the content. However in [offcanvas.css](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/offcanvas.css) there is a rule that uses absolute positioning to place it on the right top, outside the screen.

When you press 'Toggle nav', it moves the `.row` half the screen width (50%) to the left, revealing the sidebar.

---

#### Why is the sidebar shown for screen widths between 768px and 992px?

Your problem is caused by the `.container` placed around the `.row`. A container has a fixed width for viewports above 768px. You can solve this by using `width: auto` for small screens.

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .container-smooth-sm {
        width: auto;
        max-width: none;
    }
}
```

---

#### A more advanced off canvas plugin

For my projects, this approach proved to limited. Therefor I've created the [offcanvas plugin](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas) and [navmenu](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/components/#navmenu) component. The plugin can also be used to show the navbar as offcanvas menu for small screens.

Here are some examples using the Jasny Bootstrap offcanvas plugin

- [Slide in effect](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu/)
- [Push effect](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-push/)
- [Reveal effect](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-reveal/)
- [Offcanvas navbar](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navbar-offcanvas/)

Comment: Excellent! `.container-smooth-sm` added to the containing div did the trick, thank you very much @Jasny-Arnold-Daniels

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Very simple and useful. @Jasny-Arnold-Daniels

Comment: @jasny how to incorporate this with the top navbar of the bootstrap? Instead of it being slide down from the top I want to change it to slide-in from left. In your example it seems that you have replaced the original top fixed navbar with a new one. Please shed some light on this.